# Implementing pure virtual function with common details for derived classes (c++)

Tags: c++

Consider the following abstract class:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

template <class T>
class List
{
    public:
        List(){}
        virtual bool isEmpty() const=0;
        virtual void Set(int index, T value)=0;
        virtual int getSize() const=0;
        virtual void add(T value)=0;
        virtual T Remove(int index)=0;
        virtual ~List(){}

        virtual void foo()=0; 

    protected:

        int m_size;

    private:
};
#endif // LIST_H
```

Assume I have a class that inherits from List, say DynamicArray.

Is it considered bad programming to implement the pure virtual function `foo()`, so that when I implement `foo()` in the derived class I can just call the base class `foo()` and then add whatever is necessary for the derived class?

Comment: If `foo` make sense to have some functionality implemented in the base class then implement it in the base class

Comment: You seem to have forgotten a question. But then please only ask one question per question.

Comment: There can be some value in having an empty implementation in the base class.  Then derived classes only need to override the function if they want to.

Comment: if you provide an implementation in the base, then it isnt a pure virtual function anymore.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number -- the `= 0` makes it a pure virtual function; it must be overridden in a derived class. Providing an implementation is a convenience; it doesn't change that requirement.

Comment: @PaulSanders -- providing an empty implementation (or any other implementation) is orthogonal to whether it's pure virtual. If it's pure virtual (i.e., specified with `= 0`) it must be overridden in a derived class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Maybe I wasnt clear enough. The question is: Assume that what foo() does is printing the fields values to the screen. Assume I have 10 fields in the base class and 15 fields in any other derived class. I want to obligate any derived class to implement foo() and so I set it to be pure virtual, but I also would like to implement foo() in the base class so I can just call it in the implementation of any other derived class and then just print the rest 5 fields. Is it acceptable?

Comment: The question ends with _"Also if"_. I'm curious what it meant to say. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70851796/edit) the question.

Comment: @DirichletIsaPartyPooper [edit] your question to add your "the question is:" comment, and to remove "Also if"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number -- You can provide an implementation in the base class, even if the function is pure virtual.  The template design pattern is where you would see it done, where the derived class *must* implement the function, and has the option (or even requirement, depending on the docs) to call the concrete base class implementation in some way.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I got confused with terminology of `=0` vs "pure virtual" vs "derived class must provide implementation (or is abstract)". Its an area where my mental model is just too simple :/ have to do some reading...

Comment: @DirichletIsaPartyPooper For that particular pattern, consider turning it on its head - the base has a non-virtual function that first prints its own data, then calls a pure virtual function that it doesn't implement.

Comment: I have found a few *tangential* use cases for having a pure virtual member function to have its own implementation.  For those use cases, they were for debugging and diagnostic purposes when the virtual member function was called at bad times, such as in a constructor or destructor.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number -- Well, it's a good thing in C++, it doesn't have all of those restrictions that a language like Java has on abstract classes.   The only requirement with an abstract class in C++ is that the derived class must implement the pure functions -- that's it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually my ignorance is due to learning OO with Java (and because C++ has so many things that are more fun than OO ;)

Comment: If you want to print the fields in `foo` consider storing your fields in `std::map`s of `<std::any>` or of `<std::variant>` (and if high performance does not absolutely matter, but then you would not use virtual inheritance). Or use any of the packages for serialization or ORM (Object-Relational Mappers). They all have to deal with the same task to list and output the member variables. And they have found a variety of solutions for it.

Comment: See chapters Databases - ORM entries - and Serialization (non-binary and only the comfortable automatized ones): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There's two things to address here; first off, the easy thing. What you are requesting is not possible; by definition, a 'pure' virtual function *cannot* have an implementation in the base class. If you have `virtual void foo() {/* some default implementation */}` then it is no longer a 'pure' virtual function, it's just a virtual function.</strike>

Today I learned that you can provide an implementation for a pure virtual function.

The question of whether it's good practice or not is a squishy thing; it's really going to depend on the project you're working on and the patterns that have already been established there. And regardless of what you pick, it's liable to be a bit of a holy war; as far as I know, there's no definitive answer here.

So here's my personal opinions on the matter.

At this point, I've seen a *lot* of misuse and abuse of this pattern. Having trees of inheritance (or god forbid, graphs), where classes at the bottom rely on details of the types at the top can make it really difficult to track down issues when you're using the derived types. Because of this, I generally try to follow these guidelines

1. By and large, inheritance should be used for entirely pure interfaces. This lets you define shared interfaces without falling into the level of complexity I've had to deal with. It behaves like the `Interface` keyword in Java. Mostly.
2. Prefer other patterns, like composition, or having helper functions living outside the class; these patterns tend to lend themselves better to unit-testability.
3. If you do share implementation details from the base type to the children, it needs to be *very* strictly defined. You'll reach a point where you want to change it, but then that breaks some of the derived types in really subtle unexpected ways. Strict definitions can help avoid this.
4. If you inherit types that aren't strict interfaces, try to keep the depth of inheritance short. It's harder to reason about a class that inherits a type that inherits a type that inherits a type, where its behavior depends on not only the parent type, but also how the parent type interacts with its parent.

There is absolutely merit to using inheritance to provide shared functionality; I've seen it used incredibly well (see the QT library). But I believe it takes a higher level of discipline to pull off in a maintainable manner, and as such I try to avoid it in my own code because there's often a lot of other factors that weight against personal discipline like deadlines.

As is the case with any pattern, it's possible to write code that is 'good' or 'bad' using this one (for some definitions of good and bad). I personally find it easier to write 'bad' code using this one.

Comment: You can have both a pure virtual, and an implementation.  The implementation cannot be defined inline with the declaration though.

Comment: "by definition, a 'pure' virtual function cannot have an implementation in the base class" - that's totally incorrect. There are cases where the only way to enforce class to be abstract is by having pure virtual destructor and destructor of the base class is ALWAYS called by derived classes hence MUST BE DEFINED.

Comment: A pure virtual function is a virtual function that's marked `= 0`. There's nothing that prevents it from having a definition.

Comment: Yeah I get it, I was wrong on the internet. The post has been corrected. I've never seen this used; and in fact was taught that it was not allowed. Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: Re: "By and large, inheritance should be used for entirely pure interfaces" -- nonsense. The fact that you've seen bad uses of non-interface inheritance does not mean that it's inherently bad.